# creating XML from SQL TABLE with column patterns

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq

I have a table with columns below,

```
SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.NUMBER|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.DATE|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.ARP_CODE
```

and the XML output I need to have is like below

```
<SALES_ORDERS>
  <ORDER_SLIP>
    <NUMBER>TEST</NUMBER>
    <DATE>02.09.2014</DATE>
    <ARP_CODE>CARI1</ARP_CODE>
  </ORDER_SLIP>
</SALES_ORDERS>
```

I need to create the xml according to column name which include full path way from the top.

How can I achive such an XML file from such a table? I can use LINQ if it is necessary but I am not sure how to do it?

Comment: have you looked into the [FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) command ??

Comment: I have looked into it but It doesnt do what I need

Comment: with the way the data is formatted out of the box sure. but what about writing a query with table variables that arrange the data in a way that it tricks  FOR XML into displaying the data correctly.

Comment: I want to solve it with a very dynamic way. I have many xml types. So my code should work for all types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too Easy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string SQL = "Enter Your SQL Select string here";
            string connStr = "Enter You connection string here";

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, connStr);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            ds.DataSetName = "SALES_ORDERS";

            ds.WriteXml(FILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
        }
    }
}
​
```